# Large mysql insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert, timeout

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
    id,lat,lon,sequence,dist
    98372,40.535257,-111.871612,1,0.0
    98372,40.536023,-111.872235,2,0.1001
    98372,40.535629,-111.872599,3,0.1335
    98372,40.535499,-111.872559,4,0.1758
    ...etc
```

This file can be 863650 lines long! (34MB)

I need to insert each line as a row in a MySQL database using a MyISAM engine. (I'm assuming this would be the fastest)

I'm hosting on GoDaddy's servers so I don't have a lot of control over apache and mysql configurations.
This is what I have currently which would work except it takes about 6+ minutes and the server times out after 2 so it never finishes:

```
    $raw = file_get_contents('file.txt');
    $lines = explode("\r\n", $raw);
    $tablename = 'tablename';
    $tableHeaders = 'id,lat,lon,sequence,dist';
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        $line_values = explode(",", $line);
        $sqlValues = "VALUES(";
        foreach($line_values as $value) {
            $sqlValues .=  "'$value',";
        }
        $sqlValues = substr($sqlValues, 0, -1) . ")";
        $sqlSyntax = "INSERT INTO $tablename ($tableHeaders) $sqlValues";
        $mysqlcon->query($sqlSyntax);
    }
```

Can this be optimized better? Or is it possible to build a GIANT insert statement like:

```
    "INSERT INTO table (id,lat,lon,sequence,dist)
    VALUES (98372,40.535257,-111.871612,1,0.0),
    (98372,40.536023,-111.872235,2,0.1001),
    (98372,40.535629,-111.872599,3,0.1335),
    (98372,40.535499,-111.872559,4,0.1758),
    ...etc (863647 more lines)"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use INSERT Query into Foreach Loop?

Comment: @Chandresh, what do you mean? Is that what I'm doing in the first foreach example I have posted in my question?

Answer (score 5):

Build the giant INSERT, like

```
"INSERT INTO table (id,lat,lon,sequence,dist)
VALUES (98372,40.535257,-111.871612,1,0.0),
(98372,40.536023,-111.872235,2,0.1001),
(98372,40.535629,-111.872599,3,0.1335),
(98372,40.535499,-111.872559,4,0.1758),
...etc (863647 more lines)"
```

This will be many times faster. When I have faced similar problems, using a single huge query has often been 1,000 times faster than individual queries.

Note: due to memory limitations, you may want to "chunk" the inserts every 1,000 or 5,000 rows; 863,650 rows will likely exceed the maximum available memory on a shared server.

**EDIT** If you can, do [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html). This may not be available on a GoDaddy shared hosting plan for security reasons, but you can try it. You will want something like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.txt' /* change to fit your path */
INTO TABLE `table` /* Is "table" really your table's name? If so, you should pick something more descriptive... */
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' /* because your data is separated by commas */
/* See my note below about LINES TERMINATED BY */
IGNORE 1 LINES /* skip the headers */
(id,lat,lon,sequence,dist) /* the column names */
```

You may need a `LINES TERMINATED BY` clause.  [From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html):

> If you have generated the text file on a Windows system, you might have to use LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' to read the file properly, because Windows programs typically use two characters as a line terminator. Some programs, such as WordPad, might use \r as a line terminator when writing files. To read such files, use LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'.

Comment: @zinking: See my edits above. That page doesn't provide one method for loading data; it summarizes two. On a shared host, `LOAD DATA` may not be an option. Also, the page you linked to is very outdated, by the way -- 5.0 is 8 years old now.

Comment: Thank you @EdCottrell! Unfortunately, LOAD DATA is not an option for me since I'm on a shared hosting account, however building the giant insert statement is the answer, worked like a charm.